# select query is not working through Where IN Clause?

Tags: php, mysql

need help to solve select query problem but problem is that i can't fetch `ids`rows from database through `WHERE IN (pid) clause`. Select query fetching all `ids` from database from `IN (pid)`?

1)`if session pid is 29 then it should be select only 27 id` why it is showing all `ids` if `session pid is 29`?

2) How do i select multiple id through two different PID?

**Page1 Where Session Pid Creating**

```
$_SESSION['pid']=array();   
$_SESSION['pid'][]= implode (",",$_POST['pid']);
```

**Page2 Where I Want To Use Select Query**

```
$pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (pid)")
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    <input type="text" name="wid[]" value="<?php echo $row['wid']//[$j]; ?>" />
<?php  }?>
```

**Page3 Where I Want To Use Wid**

```
$max=count($_REQUEST['wid']);
for($a=0; $a<$max; $a++){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE mywishlist SET     
        cusername='".$_SESSION['username']."',uid='".$_SESSION['id']."', 
        email='".$email."'  where id='".$_REQUEST['wid'][$a]."'") 
    or die ("Cart Email Query");
}
```

**Databse Image**

[image]

**Page2 Live Image**

[image]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that you use pid and not $pid in the where clause of your query.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN ($pid)")
```

Comment: Robert Rozas did, thanks to him :) if you dont get it check out mysql doc on where in.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (pid)")
```

Should be:

```
$pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN ($pid)")
```

The reason why it shows all the result it's because you have pid in (pid)....taking pid as the field pid on your table, so for every row on the first row you said:

```
pid value = 25
SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (25)
pid value = 26
SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (26)
```

And for all the rows the same...you are comparing with the value pid in you table.

---------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

Because this:

```
SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN ($pid)
```

If you make an echo to $pid, it shoul looks like, as example:

```
24,25
```

Then you select should looks like:

```
SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (24,25)
```

Ooops, you code should be more safely if you use mysql_real_scape_string

```
"SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (".mysql_real_scape_string($pid).")";
```

I added this fiddle if you dont know how to works with an array of inputs:

```
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2fd-p20
```

--------------------------UPDATE2--------------------------------

With this code on my fiddle you have an array of inputs:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['friend']))
{ $arr = array();
 foreach ($_POST['friend'] as $value) {
   if(!empty($value))
$arr[] = $value;
 }

 //here you have you array of values in your session var

 $_SESSION['pid'] = implode(",",$arr);
 }
?>
```

Then only use it this way:

```
$pid = $_SESSION['pid'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (".$pid.")")
```

PS: Dont use mysql extension...go for mysqli or PDO.

Comment: robert can you guide for this ?? `i want update table id with session username, session uid & session email if there are two pids? this function is use for page3?`

Comment: Yeah it should works...for pid 24 ith should print 2 input on page 2 whit the values 21 and 25....on page3 you should make a var_dump to $_REQUEST['wid'] ...or an echo to $max to see how much values are you getting from page2

Comment: now i need to updated query and update columns where two different pids?

Comment: The query should works for diferents pid...i update my answer ;)

Comment: `echo var_dump($_REQUEST['wid']); echo $max=count($_REQUEST['wid']);` display only one `pid`

Comment: Im gonna make a fiddle to explain you how to retrieve the array of pid: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2fd-p20

Comment: i have tried that code in sql `SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (24,25) ` and it is showing two different id from two different pid but problem how do i set variable instead of 24,25

Comment: Check the fiddle to know how to work with array of inputs...with that arra you only need: "SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (".implode(",", $arr).")";

Comment: you mean like this `foreach ($_SESSION['pid'] as $value) {
  if(!empty($value))
 $arr[] = $value;
}
`

Comment: yes....in that way you have you $arr with all the not empty values on the form submitted...try inserting values in random inputs...only retrieve the non empty inputs on the $arr....then you use imploe on the in condition ;)

Comment: see method now `foreach ($_SESSION['pid'] as $value) {
  if(!empty($value))
 echo $arr[] = $value;
} SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN (".implode(",", $arr).")` now showing only single `id`?